# Ошибка "Not enough information to infer type variable" при объявлении data binding во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, android-data-binding

При объявлении data binding во фрагменте получаю ошибку:

> Not enough information to infer type variable T

На строке:

```kotlin
val listItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
```

Код:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    val listItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)

    initViews(rootView)

    setupViews()
    return rootView
}
```

Comment: тут пример как нужно https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments, а работать уже с созданными вью лучше в onViewCreated

Comment: это немного не то, я использую data binding, а не view binding

Comment: Это не важно, генерится такое же имя и создаётся (инфлейтится) точно так же

Comment: @Sunbey13 какой тип вы ожидаете у переменной `listItemBinding`? Видимо, компилятор не может догадаться, ему нужно подсказать, указать тип явно.

Comment: @Vadik к сожалению, в примерах (согласно документации) не указан какой тип следует ожидать, поэтому не могу его указать(

Comment: Попробуйте указать `FragmentDashboardBinding`.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) есть примеры. Если посмотреть примеры на Java, то там виден тип. Для лэйаута `my_layout.xml` сгенерируется класс `MyLayoutBinding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор сообщает о том, что ему недостаточно информации, чтобы [вывести тип](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-inference.html):

> Not enough information to infer type variable T

Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, укажите явно тип при вызове функции `inflate`. Если вы хотите надуть `lalala.xml`, то тип будет `LalalaBinding`:

```kotlin
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<LalalaBinding>(R.layout.lalala,..)
```

Либо укажите явно тип переменной:

```kotlin
val binding: LalalaBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(R.layout.lalala,..)
```

Comment: при этом нужно импортировать класс, в котором используется databinding в xml-файле.
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>```
```<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"```
    ```xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">```
    ```<data>```
       ```<import type="com.testscreen.MainActivity"/>```
    ```</data>```
...
```</layout>```